# Accessing UIImagePickerController Camera's Preview Screen

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, preview

I am working with a basic `UIImagePickerController`. I have read about camera overlays and am not ready / don't need to dive into that world yet.

After the user takes a photo, the `UIImagePickerController` displays a "Preview" screen. All I want to do is change the text on the button on the preview screen from "Use" to "Upload".

It seems to me that there should be a very easy way to access this, but I have found very few references to the "Preview" screen.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality is not exposed in the SDK. There is no way to customize the Preview screen.

Comment: Looks like I will have to work with an overlay if I want to do this.